# Localization without the (old or new) Gui Builder?

Tags: codenameone

About localization, I studied the developer guide, section "Localization & Internationalization (L10N & I18N)", at:
https://www.codenameone.com/manual/misc-features.html

and this video:
http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---localizetranslate-my-application-apply-i18nl10n-internationalizationlocalization-to-my-app.html

Both of them seems referring to the old gui builder.
I'm writing a new app without using the (old or new) gui builder, so my question is if I can localize my app using the Localization tool inside Codename One Designer.

For example, see this screenshot:
[image: Localization in Codename One Designer]

I have two Buttons with the labels "LOGIN-Button" and "SIGNUP-Button", but they are not translated automatically. I wasn't able to use the following line of code, as suggested in the developer guide, because I haven't any reference to "res":

```
UIManager.getInstance().setBundle(res.getL10N("l10n", local));
```

I was able to translate my app with the following manual code. Is there any way to use the Localization tool inside Codename One Designer without manual coding?

```
// LOCALIZATION
    // Retrive the device language (as an ISO 639 two letter code)
    String local = L10NManager.getInstance().getLanguage();
    Log.p("The device language is: " + local);

    //Creates the bundle that maps strings in the local language
    HashMap EnglishBundle = new HashMap<String, String>();
    EnglishBundle.put("LOGIN-Button", "LOG IN");
    EnglishBundle.put("SIGNUP-Button", "SIGN UP");
    EnglishBundle.put("@rtl", "false");

    HashMap ItalianBudle = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ItalianBudle.put("LOGIN-Button", "ENTRA");
    ItalianBudle.put("SIGNUP-Button", "REGISTRATI");
    ItalianBudle.put("@rtl", "false");

    switch (local) {
        case "it":
            UIManager.getInstance().setBundle(ItalianBudle);
            break;
        default:
            UIManager.getInstance().setBundle(EnglishBundle);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The localization tool has nothing to do with the GUI builder. It's a part of the designer tool which also handles theming, multi-image and other features all of which are useful for handcoded apps just as much as visual apps.

The only GUI builder specific capability in that video is auto-generating the keys from the GUI form.

Since localization is just a lookup map you can use properties files and don't have to keep the data within your app source.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Please can you provide me an example of code to make the localization working in my app (using the localization tool)?

Comment: You already wrote it: `UIManager.getInstance().setBundle(res.getL10N("l10n", local));`